Whitelisting Azure IP Ranges in Sentinel
I have this query that returns the values of public IP ranges from Azure. These ranges are ones I want to whitelist in an existing alert that flags Suspicous Resource Deployments.
// Pulling Azure IPs from link and parsing them in to a readable format for query.
let AzureIPRangesPublicCloud = (externaldata(changeNumber:string, cloud:string, values: dynamic)
[@"https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20240722.json"]
with (format="multijson"));
let AzureSubnetRangeWhitelist = AzureIPRangesPublicCloud
| mvexpand values
| extend addressPrefixes = parse_json(parse_json(values).properties).addressPrefixes
| mvexpand addressPrefixes
| project  addressPrefixes;
AzureSubnetRangeWhitelist


Here is the query for the Suspicous Resource Deployment
  // Add or remove operation names below as per your requirements. For operations lists, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#all
  let szOperationNames = dynamic(["Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write", "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write", "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write"]);
  let starttime = 14d;
  let endtime = 1d;
  let RareCaller = AzureActivity
  | where TimeGenerated between (ago(starttime) .. ago(endtime))
  | where OperationNameValue in~ (szOperationNames)
  | summarize count() by CallerIpAddress, Caller, OperationNameValue, bin(TimeGenerated,1d)
  // Returns all the records from the right side that don't have matches from the left.
  | join kind=rightantisemi (
  AzureActivity
  | where TimeGenerated > ago(endtime)
  | where OperationNameValue in~ (szOperationNames)
  | summarize StartTimeUtc = min(TimeGenerated), EndTimeUtc = max(TimeGenerated), ActivityTimeStamp = make_set(TimeGenerated,100), ActivityStatusValue = make_set(ActivityStatusValue,100), CorrelationIds = make_set(CorrelationId,100), ResourceGroups = make_set(ResourceGroup,100), ResourceIds = make_set(_ResourceId,100), ActivityCountByCallerIPAddress = count()
  by CallerIpAddress, Caller, OperationNameValue) on CallerIpAddress, Caller, OperationNameValue;
  RareCaller
  | extend Name = iif(Caller has '@',tostring(split(Caller,'@',0)[0]),"")
  | extend UPNSuffix = iif(Caller has '@',tostring(split(Caller,'@',1)[0]),"")
  | extend AadUserId = iif(Caller !has '@',Caller,"")

How do I compare the addressPrefixes that are in the form "4.145.74.52/30" to the CallerIpAddress form? And essentially whitelist alerts where the CallerIpAddress falls within the range of the json file?

Can you provide your expected results?

Have you tried using ipv4_is_in_any_range() function?
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kusto/query/ipv4-is-in-any-range-function?view=microsoft-fabric
